# can i add segmented control at the top without scrolling in Tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a uitableview on my screen and i added uiview at the top of it to put a segmented control in it. My question is that when i scroll the page, segmented control is also scrolling with the table cells.. how can i remove scrolling just for segmented control?

```
- (void)setExtractedImageForTableView:(UIImage *)extractedImage {
self.documentImageView.image = nil;
self.documentImageView = nil;
self.documentImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:extractedImage];
self.documentImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(extractedImage.size, CGSizeZero)) {
    self.documentImageView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.view.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.tableView.frame) + 70, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), (extractedImage.size.height/extractedImage.size.width) * CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame));
    self.segmentedView.frame = self.documentImage.frame;
    [self.segmentedView addSubview:self.segment];
    [self.segmentedView addSubview:self.documentImageView];
    [self.tableView.tableHeaderView addSubview:self.segment];
    [self.tableView.tableHeaderView addSubview:self.documentImageView];
    CGRect frame = self.documentImageView.frame;
    frame.size.height = self.documentImageView.frame.size.height + 100;
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 300);
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = frame;
}
}
```

Comment: do like add the segment control in top of the frame and start/create the tableview in after that segmentcontrol frame.

Comment: just add unsegmented control to uiview. Not to tableview

Comment: [self.segmentedView addSubview:self.segment]; .. adding this is not working :/ @Uma

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps:

1. first add view of full 320*480.
2. on top of it add segment control of required size.
3. then add a scrollview of left out height = (480 - segment control height).
4. in the left out height add another view.
5. on top of it add tableview.

this will create your UI.
Then add delegate methods of scrollview. and you will get what you want

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Comment: i am using table sections after my segmentedView, not table view Cells in tableviewController.  You think, Is it gonna still work?

Comment: I think according to what I have understood, the solution to your problem will Adding a tableView and mentioning how many sections You need programmatically.

Comment: no i am sorry maybe i explained to you wrongly. Let me explain again, okay I have a table View Controller and inside of this controller, i have a segmented control in a UIView and couple of tableViewSections. When i run the app sections and segmented control are scrolling together. But i need to immobilize segmented control at the top. It shouldnt scroll with sections. Because i need to see segmented control at the top, even if i scrool the page..

Comment: just resize your scrollview size to only that of tableview sections. Remove it from segmente control

Comment: Table View Sections are not like table view cells.. I cant put them in a scrool View.. :/

Comment: No ScrollView is just as a UIView.Add your table on scrollview

Comment: you mean i should add a view and put all sections in it and add a scrool for that view?

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. View add on screen size ex (320 *568)
```

2. Top bar add segment control on view
3. And Add table view after segment control

   Add datasource and delegate of tableview

Comment: idea is good, adding view is okay but Table View Sections are not going inside of that view.. this is the problem. There are no table view cells in Table View Controller, there are sections, they are different things :/

Answer (score -1):

You have two options:

1- place segmented control above your tableview not inside you tableview header, because i suppose you stick it with tableview view header that why he scrolling.

2- Place your segmented control in your top header if you want your tableview take your whole screen. You just set the title view of your navigation controller title view with your segmented controller view.

---